# How to share Ubuntu directory for Windows application?

Tags: windows, shared-folders

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 in the same LAN.
What to do to share Ubuntu directory for Windows application?
I.e. Windows app can read and write files to Ubuntu directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to connect an Ubuntu machine to a Windows Workgroup. Various things do work but not file share access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254459/trying-to-connect-an-ubuntu-machine-to-a-windows-workgroup-various-things-do-wo)

Comment: I do not see how can I share directory , what I need to do.

Comment: [Google found this](https://www.debugpoint.com/guide-how-share-folder-between-ubuntu-linux-windows/)

Comment: It seems it is the solution. Add your answer and I'll mark it. it is not so easy to open in Windows: 10 works, but Windows Server 2019 cannot open but I will investigate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your "backend" you need to create a network share of your local folder. Ubuntu provides you with a menu entry like ("Local network share").

Thus you need a running smbd.service on your local machine. The `/etc/smbd.conf`,which is its config file, can be setup to suite the needs of your counterpart (e.g a Windows client or server expects a certain workgroup).

After you change your smd.conf, you'll need to restart your smbd service. Uusally this works:

`sudo systemctl restart smb`

A basic, illustrated example is provided [here](https://www.debugpoint.com/guide-how-share-folder-between-ubuntu-linux-windows/)

Comment: Also,+ :  for Win Server 2019 etc need manual intervention to allow it to see and Ubuntu shared folder